# How to use ckpt data model into tensorflow iOS example?

Tags: ios, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am quiet new to Machine learning, and I am working on iOS app for object detection using tensorflow, I have been using the sample data model that is provided by tensorflow example in the form of .pb (graph.pb) file which works just fine with object detection.

But My backend team has given me model2_BN.ckpt for data model file, I have tried to research on how to use this file and I have no clue. 
 Is it possible to use the ckpt file on client side as data model? If yes How can I use it in the iOS tensorflow example as data model?

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: answering it myself.

Answer (score 2):

This one from my backend developer:

```
The .ckpt is the model given by tensorflow which includes all the 
weights/parameters in the model.  The .pb file stores the computational 
graph.  To make tensorflow work we need both the graph and the 
parameters.  There are two ways to get the graph: 
(1) use the python program that builds it in the first place (tensorflowNetworkFunctions.py).
(2) Use a .pb file (which would have to be generated by tensorflowNetworkFunctions.py). 

.ckpt file is were all the intelligence is.
```